# Touch событие на айфонах

Tags: javascript, safari, touch

Проще говоря не работает перелистывание слайдера только на айфонах я так понял сафари не очень дружит с событиями тач
https://cellsium.github.io/waxom
Вот то что я наваял и проблема в последнем слайдере(нижнем) не могу понять как подружить сафари и тач события js.

```
    let touch = 0;
    let up = 0;

    let touchD = 0;
    let touchU = 0;

    function clickDown(e) {
        touch = e.clientX;
    }

    function clickUp(e) {
        up = e.clientX;
        if (up < touch) {
            leftSlide();
        } else {
            rightSlide();
        }
    }

    function touchDown(e) {
        touchD = e.changedTouches[e.changedTouches.length - 1].pageX;
    }

    function touchUp(e) {
        touchU = e.changedTouches[e.changedTouches.length - 1].pageX;
        if (touchU < touchD) {
            leftSlide();
        } else {
            rightSlide();
        }
    }

    line.addEventListener('mousedown', clickDown);
    line.addEventListener('touchstart', touchDown);
    line.addEventListener('mouseup', clickUp);
    line.addEventListener('touchend', touchUp);
```

Comment: Сюда требуется добавить минимальный код, воспроизводящий проблему. Это делается для других людей со схожим вопросом. Чтобы они не искали какие там слайдеры были в декабрьской версии вашего шаблона сайта.

Comment: Посмотрел ваш код. Вам для отслеживания движения не нужны были `touchstart` и `touchend`, а нужен только `touchmove`. Вот он то как раз и отсутствует в вашем коде.

Comment: при нажатии(касании) записывается начальное положение мыши(пальца) при отпускании вычисляется движение исходя из начальной позиции пальца или мышы (влево или в право).
не могу догнать как тачмувом определить направление движения пальца (влево или вправо)

Comment: На ифонах так не делается, на ифоне ты чувствуешь объект, который перемещаешь. Объект под пальцем ходит плавно, как будто мацая силиконовую грудь.

Comment: движение слайдера в реальном времени не предполагалось

Comment: Ну, в любом случае это было бы круче, понятнее, нагляднее и в стиле iphone. В случае с тач-событиями немного легче чем с мышкой. Так как мышка может перемещаться без нажатых кнопок и с нажатыми кнопками. А touchmove предусматривает перемещение в любом случае. А определить направление легко.

Comment: кусок кода с тачмувом для размышления можно в студию ?

Comment: @DiD  а в случае обычной груди как объект движется? Менее плавно? С подергиваниями?

Comment: @axmed2004 я это написал к тому, что на ios принято, что при перемещении по экрану объекта пальцем, объект под пальцем повторяет движение пальца.

Comment: @Дядя Ваня Посмотрите код этого слайдера https://jsfiddle.net/56t7dr8g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я добавил с компа, протестировал на мобильном, свайпы работают. Для отслеживания свайпа конечно нужно отслеживать и событие `touchstart` и событие `touchend`. Так что, я был не прав в комменте. Но координаты перемещения пальца доступны только из события `touchmove`. Для плавного перемещения картинки нужен только `touchmove`.

```js
var swipeFunc = {
    touches : {
        "touchstart": {"x":-1, "y":-1}, 
        "touchmove" : {"x":-1, "y":-1}, 
        "touchend"  : false,
        "direction" : "undetermined"
    },
    touchHandler: function(event) {
        var touch;
        if (typeof event !== 'undefined'){  
            event.preventDefault(); 
            if (typeof event.touches !== 'undefined') {
                touch = event.touches[0];
                switch (event.type) {
                    case 'touchstart':
                    case 'touchmove':
                        swipeFunc.touches[event.type].x = touch.pageX;
                        swipeFunc.touches[event.type].y = touch.pageY;
                        break;
                    case 'touchend':
                        swipeFunc.touches[event.type] = true;
                        if (swipeFunc.touches.touchstart.x > -1 && swipeFunc.touches.touchmove.x > -1) {
                            swipeFunc.touches.direction = swipeFunc.touches.touchstart.x < swipeFunc.touches.touchmove.x ? "right" : "left";
                            
                            // DO STUFF HERE
                            alert(swipeFunc.touches.direction);
                        }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    init: function() {
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', swipeFunc.touchHandler, false); 
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', swipeFunc.touchHandler, false);  
        document.addEventListener('touchend', swipeFunc.touchHandler, false);
    }
};
swipeFunc.init();
```

Про то, что писал в комментариях, можно реализовать на чистом CSS. Песочница почему-то режет CSS. Добавил сюда: https://jsfiddle.net/56t7dr8g/

Comment: preventdefault решает! код хорош,спасибо DID